# Agent.txt in User Folder

Tags: windows-8.1

I just got a new laptop with Windows 8.1 and under the user directory (e.g. `C:\Users\USER_NAME\`) there is a file called: **agent.txt**

I ran a Virus Scan and didn't find any malware... Does anyone know what creates the file and whether it is safe to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a new laptop with Windows 8.1 too but in my user directory I find **no** agent.txt. It should be safe to delete as Windows wouldn't put any important files there for you to tamper with.

What is the size of the file? **When was the file created?**(That should give you some idea about the origin of the file)Try opening the text file in sandbox mode and see what's in it although I really doubt that there will be any virus/malware of any kind.

If you aren't sure, then delete it (not Shift-Delete) so the file will be in the Recycle Bin. If nothing happens after a few days, then you can clean the Recycle Bin so that it is actually deleted. Also you might want to check if the file is regenerated in the directory after some time :)

Or you can just leave it there-that's also a viable option!

**EDIT:** [Here's another user in the same situation as you](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1724696/random-notepad-file-appearing-user-folder.html). I guess it does regenerate after all! My advice would be to just leave it as it is.